# Why do I have to duplicate the labels used for the classification process?

Tags: matlab, dsp-core

I'm using the BCI Competition dataset IV 2a. I'm working on Left & right hand movement.  I extracted data of channels (Fz,Cz,Pz). 
I filtered data [8-30], then normalized it.
I calculated the common spatial patterns of the training dataset using the CSP.m of the Biosig toolbox
I want to use the "train_sc" to classify my data.
My question is why do I need to duplicate the labels of each event? 
ex: 
for each right hand event (750 samples) I must have 750 label = 1
for each left    hand event (750 samples) I must have 750 label = 2

labels = repmat(classlabel’,n,1)’;   %where n is the number of samples/event
CC = train_sc(features,labels,'LDA');

Does that mean that classification is done on samples rather than events?
Is each sample classified independently?!!!

The results I got are very disappointing. I've tried many classifiers but the best accuracy I got was 0.5 
I need to know what I'm doing wrong.

I've read too much on CSP & classification of the eeg signals, but still I feel that I'm missing many things :(
Any help please.

Best Regards,
Sahar Selim

Comment: Sounds like they are. How many events do you have in the set?

Comment: 72 (left hand) & 72 (right hand)

Comment: I would think you would only have one class value per event. So you would have (72 + 72) feature vectors with dimension 3x750 and (72+72) class labels. Otherwise it would be (72+72)*750 feature vectors with dimension 3 and (72 + 72)*750 class labels?

Comment: Sahar I used to work on Brain signal analysis before using Common spatial patterns algorithm for two class as well as multi class (4 and higher) And i believe there are many useful resources for BCI in this webpage and a very good matlab toolbox <https://sites.google.com/site/fabienlotte/code-and-softwares>

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.